# Continually process results of multi-thread worker

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Let's say we've got some SQL queries and want to display the results. Processing takes some time, so I do it multi-threaded.
The following works quite well for me. I reduced the code to the important parts and would be glad to get some comments on it:

Queries and results are stored in thread safe collections.

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> sqlQueries;
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ResultSet> sqlResults;
```

In the GUI thread I start the worker threads which continuously get new queries from the sqlQueries, execute them, and put the results into sqlResults.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    executorService.execute(new QueryThread(sqlResults, sqlQueries));
}
executorService.shutdown(); //threads terminate after they finish

//Result processing
while ((!executorService.isTerminated() || !sqlResults.isEmpty())) {
    Thread.Sleep(100); //sleep for some time
    while(!sqlResults.isEmpty()) {
        //process available results
    }
}
```

Within the threads I do sth like:

```
do{
    currentSqlQuery = sqlQueries.poll();
    if(currentSqlQuery != null) {
        sqlResults.add(executeQuery(currentSqlQuery));
    }
} while (currentSqlQuery != null)
```

Comment: What is still not clear: Is it getting the answer or processing the answer what takes longer and so requires multiple threads?

Comment: Getting the answer takes longer and is processed in multiple threads. If new answers pop up, they are processed and shown on the GUI.

Comment: OK, so the GUI thread is starting the worker threads and doing the answer processing?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We on [codereview.se] review **"real code"**. Please include the **actual** code you want reviewed in your question, instead of the current stub code ;) For more information, check the [help/on-topic]

Comment: alright, I rearranged the code a little bit. Although, I think putting everything on here would make it less readable.

Comment: If your code has readability issues, our Java reviewers are pretty good at addressing those, too! I'm not going to vote to close this question because it *seems* to contain the bare minimum reviewable code, but I encourage you to simply post the whole class here and see what reviews you get.

Comment: @Vogel612 that's awkward: First, you tell the question owner to move from Stack Overflow to Code Review, and then you vote to close the question!

Comment: @isnot2bad ?? I can't rmember referring OP here from SO...  linkey? Also that and VTC are different things..

Comment: @Vogel612 Hm. SO question was not there any more, so couldn't check back. Thought it were you. Sorry if I was wrong.

Comment: I deleted the original on SOF. It was not Vogel612 who referred to CR. But anyways, if on this site only proper code should be posted, I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the concept of `Executor` (and `ExecutorService`). It already acts as a queue, so you don't need to maintain a queue of your own. Your code actually creates one job per thread, and every job processes multiple questions from the queue. Instead, you should rather have one task per question:

```
Collection<String> questions = ...;
for (String question : questions) {
    executor.execute(new QueryTask(question));
}
```

Also note that you're calling your class `QuestionThread`. But it's not a *thread*, it's a *task*! Please always differ between *task* and *thread*: A *task* is a piece of work that should be done, while *threads* are a mechanism to execute tasks in parallel.

Your `QueryTask` should only execute one single query and return it as a result:

```
class QueryTask implements Callable<String> {
    private final String question;

    public QueryTask(String question) { this.question = question; }

    public String call() {
        // maybe long running
        // get and return answer!
    }
}
```

The processing part is flawed too, because you're doing a busy-wait there! Instead, you can solve your problem very elegant using a `CompletionService`. The full algorithm will then be as follows:

```
public void query(ExecutorService executor, Collection<String> questions, Consumer<String> answerConsumer) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    CompletionService ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService(executor);
    // execute all tasks
    for (String question : questions) {
        ecs.execute(new QueryTask(question));
    }

    // wait for tasks to complete and hand them over to consumer
    final int size = questions.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        answerConsumer.accept(ecs.take().get());
    }
}
```

*(The interface `Consumer` exists since Java 8; it can easily be replaced by something similar)*.

**Appendix: Calling `query` from UI thread**

Note that the calling thread is blocked until all questions and answers are processed. In case this is the UI thread, it will not be able to run UI events in the meantime. As a result, your UI will "freeze" (it will not react to any user input nor doing repaints of dirty UI regions).

To solve this problem, the call to `query` must be asnychronous and the consumer must put the result into a UI updating task and hand it over to the UI thread (how this exactly works depends on the UI framework you are using. SWT: `Display.(a)syncExec(...)`, Swing: `SwingUtilites.invokeLater(...)`, JavaFX: `Platform.runLater(...)`, ...). The following example will assume you're using JavaFX (it also uses Java 8 lambda expressions):

```
public void queryAsynchWithUIUpdate(Collection<String> questions) {
    Executor e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    e.execute(() -> {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
        query(executor, questions, answer -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                // update UI using answer, e.g.:
                answerTextField.setText(answer);
            });
        });
        executor.shutdown();
    });
    e.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This helped quite a lot. I am new to multi threaded programs and I like your approach very much.
What is not clear to me though is the use of database conncetions. With your example I will probably have to use connection pools, right?
Opening and closing a new connection for each query or using the same connection in multiple threads is probably not the best way (this was also why I originally wanted to process multiple queries in the same task).

Comment: You're welcome! JDBC `Conection`s are NOT thread safe, neither are `ResultSet`s, `Statement`s or anything similiar. A connection pool is the most reasonable solution therefor. But you can also open and close a new connection for every task,  if you keep the number of threads limited (e.g. use a fixed thread pool) and the db operations outweighs the costs for opening/closing the connections.

Comment: I wrote the other answer and I approve this message.  CompletionService is one of those forgotten little gems.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.sleep` is usually a red flag in code, especially when used to emulate a blocking call.  If you choose a different approach, such as using [CompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html), you can use `take()` to wait for an answer.

Seeing `ResultSet` as a return type in a multi-threaded context also worries me.  Who closes the `Statement` that generated it?  Consider offering a callback mechanism that can operate on the result instead:

```
// process the query and get a result set
try ( resources you've opened ) {
    callback.consume(result);
}
```